# Call another code while array.map() is running

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, es6-promise

I have the following react code:

```
{myArray.map(arr => { 
    return ( <MyComponent title={arr.ttile} /> ) 
})}
```

I would like to call a **Loading component** while the **map()** is not completely finished. Is it possible to do that? If yes, how would I do that?

Comment: It's not possible, since `map` is synchronous and you can't do any asynchronous logic in the render method.

Comment: The `map` itself will return almost immediately, surely?

Comment: why would you want that?

Comment: can you elaborate your use case?

Comment: myArray is an array of books from an outside API. It takes about 2 or 3 seconds to get it done. Now we just see the blank page. I would like to put a loading component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting your data from an API, you might want to render the data as usual, but you can get the data in the `componentDidMount` hook instead, and e.g. keep an additional piece of state `isLoading` which you can use in the render method to decide if you should show a loading component.

**Example**

```js
function getBooks() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve([{ title: "foo" }, { title: "bar" }]), 1000);
  });
}

function MyComponent(props) {
  return <div> {props.title} </div>;
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { books: [], isLoading: true };

  componentDidMount() {
    getBooks().then(books => {
      this.setState({ books, isLoading: false });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { isLoading, books } = this.state;

    if (isLoading) {
      return <div> Loading... </div>;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.books.map(book => <MyComponent title={book.title} />)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to actually be able to *see* the components being loaded behind/under the loading indicator, then it would be more challenging and would probably need more work than this proposed solution.  But if you just want a loading indicator to show while the `.map()` prototype function is working, I believe this would do the trick:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { loadingIndicator : null };
}

getArrayOfMyComponents() {
    return myArray.map((arr, index) => {
        if (index === 0) {
            const loadingIndicator = <Loading/>;
            this.setState({ loadingIndicator : loadingIndicator });
        } else if (index === myArray.length - 1) {
            this.setState({ loadingIndicator : null });
        }
        return ( <MyComponent title={arr.title} /> );
    });
}

render() {
    const arrayOfMyComponents = this.getArrayOfMyComponents();
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.loadingIndicator}
            {arrayOfMyComponents}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Array.prototype.map() is really just a fancier version of Array.prototype.forEach().  So we can leverage that fact to launch the display of the loading indicator on the first iteration and remove it on the last.

Comment: This doesn't do what you may think it does. `setState()` is asynchronous while `map()` is not. So if you call `setState` inside of `map()` it will not immediately be reflected by the component. The iteration will just continue. The correct solution would be to create a `Promise` that resolves with the mapped list and render an indicator in the mean time. Or you could use `async` `await`.

Comment: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
The error happens at line: `this.setState({ loadingIndicator : loadingIndicator });`

Answer (score 0):

you can have a boolean in a state, and just before you start array map put boolean true and run another code o component render, and then when array maps end you put that state to false, for redux im using state fetch start, fetching, fetched, and then you can take the control of situation